# Logstash Azure Event hub input , The client could not finish the operation within specified maximum execution timeout

Tags: azure, logstash, azure-eventhub

Hi Im having this Warns when I try to get events from event hub.

```
com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The client could not finish the operation within specified maximum execution timeout.
```

after those warns I get this error: Out of retries creating lease store for this Event Hub

```
        [ERROR] 2022-01-31 15: 26: 37.760 [azure_event_hubs-worker-11-fadc76f77bb4d96b880b8af84e7d4dc9af184d55efd5dfedeaaac4ad2f5a5836
        ] azureeventhubs - Event Hub encountered an error. {
          :event_hub_name=>"<edited>",
          :exception=>com.microsoft.azure.eventprocessorhost.PartitionManager$FinalException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.microsoft.azure.eventprocessorhost.ExceptionWithAction: Out of retries creating lease store for this Event Hub,
          :backtrace=>[
            "com.microsoft.azure.eventprocessorhost.PartitionManager.lambda$buildRetries$19(PartitionManager.java:278)",
            "java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:930)",
            "java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:907)",
            "java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478)",
            "java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)",
            "java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)",
            "java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)",
            "java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)",
            "java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)",
            "java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)"
          ]
        }
```

I can connect with telnet to the host and port  `<edited>.servicebus.windows.net:5671`

I also can do telnet to ports 5672 and 443

and when I use wget:

```
wget https://<edited>.servicebus.windows.net
--2022-01-31 19:55:50--  https://<edited>.servicebus.windows.net/
Resolving <edited>.servicebus.windows.net (<edited>.servicebus.windows.net)... <edited IP>
Connecting to <edited>.servicebus.windows.net (<edited>.servicebus.windows.net)|<edited IP>|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

I have other 4 pipelines working with Event Hub input pointing to diferents storage connections.

And another strange thing is that if I run the same losgtash version in a VM in my laptop, and the same pipeline, it work and the error is not shown

What may be the problem?

Comment: The issue is at the storage call. Make sure the storage account is accessible from the processor host client.

Comment: telnet wouldn't be enough?

Comment: Any TCP tool would be good enough to identify firewall/network issues. Let me know what you find out.

Comment: I can connect with telnet to <edited>.servicebus.windows.net:5671

Comment: also can do telnet to ports 5672 and 443

Comment: Failure is about Storage access. Can you check storage endpoint instead?

Comment: I dont have acces to Event Hub, a coworker has, can you think in something to check in that side?

Comment: You should check the Azure Storage access, not the Event Hubs. The PartitionManager in the provided callstack is trying to access to Storage account and it is failing.